# Do you get charged for production variants on sagemaker that have no traffic going through them?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I have a deployed model on sagemaker with two production variants. I was wondering if you get charged for both variants even if I set all the traffic to just go through one of them.

The docs on pricing are found below but I couldn't seem to find the answer to this.

https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/pricing/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be charged as long as the model is running on an instance regardless of whether the traffic is going through it or not as still the model is running on an instance.